# React-router-dom with Material-ui working but not mounting components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm working on this project: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-frog-089l2
My goal is to (as react-router-dom is supposed to work) navigate among various components using the Material-UI buttons on top. Only problem is, while the router works (I can see the mountpoint changing on the address bar), the right component does not get mounted. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 path='/studio/'
```

should be replaced with

```
path='/studio'
```

and also u should change the first route to have `exact` prop and remove it from the rest of the `Route` components

this is how your switch should look like:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
     <Route path="/studio" component={Studio} />
     <Route path="/stanzino" component={Stanzino} />
     <Route path="/affitti" component={Affitti} />
     <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Right. Still, that's not the solution to the problem

Comment: why not ? what the solution was?
notice I edited my question, there is another error which is not related that u pass `<Studio/> `instead of `Studio`

Comment: I wrote it before reading the edit. Now at least I get some error:
Error: **Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

Comment: look at the answer again I changed it again